# How to apply different styles to datagrid columns

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles, controltemplate

i'm quite new to WPF and i don't know how to use two different control template for the columns of a datagrid (that will always have 2 columns).
This is the XAML of the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="HomeSoftwareGrid"
          CanUserAddRows="false"
          ItemsSource="{Binding CollectedSoftwares}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          FontSize="15"
          ColumnWidth="*"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn"
          CellEditEnding="OnCellEditEnding"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          MaxWidth="600">
</DataGrid>
```

I'm using the property AutoGeneratingColumn to remove a specific column and edit the columns' headers

```
private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = (PropertyDescriptor)e.PropertyDescriptor;
    e.Column.Header = propertyDescriptor.DisplayName;
    if (propertyDescriptor.DisplayName == "Resources")
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else if (propertyDescriptor.DisplayName == "SoftwareStatus")
    {
        e.Column.Header = "Software Status";

    }
    else if (propertyDescriptor.DisplayName == "SoftwareName")
    {
        e.Column.Header = "Software Name";
    }
}
```

These are the content templates i want to use, the first for the first columns and the second for second one obviously :D :

```
<!-- first column style -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- second column style -->
<Style x:Key="SoftwareStatusDataGridColumn" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Rectangle x:Name="ImgPartially" Grid.Column="0"  Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Yellow">
                        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                            <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_warning}" />
                        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    </Rectangle>

                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sender` of event is DataGrid, and DataGrid can find cell style in its visual tree. Then you can assign that style to columns individually:

```
else if (propertyDescriptor.DisplayName == "SoftwareName")
{
    e.Column.Header = "Software Name";
    e.Column.CellStyle = (sender as FrameworkElement).FindResource("SoftwareStatusDataGridColumn") as Style;
}
```

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
```

this Style uses Type as a key, it will be assigned to DataGridCells by default, no need to set it explicitly from code behind

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm for the second column but seems that the first column "lose" its style: the text should be center aligned but, when it's applied the style on the second column, it becomes left aligned :S

Comment: @Sempri92, `<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">` should be assigned by default. It is working for me. But still you can declare first style with explicit key `<Style x:Key="SoftwareNameDataGridColumn" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">` etc, and use the same trick with FindResource in code behind (name will be SoftwareNameDataGridColumn)

Comment: **EDIT:**
I was missing that in my tries i've added x:Key to the first style too...everything works as it should now! thanks again!!!